# JavaScript regex to replace a character ignoring HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Once again, I need some help and I appreciate you all for being here willing to help.
I'm trying to implement a regex for a JavaScript function that will replace a string of text contained in an HTML tag, but ignoring the tag altogether.
For example:
The string I need to find and replace is the dollar sign ($),
and the HTML that I'm working with looks like this:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <input type="radio" value="$233.93" name="myInput" id="myInputId">
    <label>
        $36.<sup>07</sup>
    </label>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a dollar amount in the value attribute of the input tag, and another dollar amount inside the label tag.
All this HTML is contained within a td (table cell), which in turn is part of a table, for which I'm implementing a sorting by column functionality.
My problem is that I have not been able to come up with a regex that would ignore the HTML tags altogether and match only the string inside my label tag (`$36.<sup>07</sup>`).
I put together this regex: `/[$](?=(\d{2,5}[.<]))/`
This regex works, but only half way, because it matches the first dollar sign in the value of the value attribute, granted the regex it's not set to global, because it would replace all dollar sign and I don't wan't to do that, and I cannot change the structure of the HTML either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: +1 to amber, do not use regex to parse html

Comment: I think I'm mistaken, I'm not trying to parse HTML with a regex, I'm trying to extract a value and test it against a regex.
Is that the same thing?

Comment: jnkrois, you should edit your title+post to clarify **what** you're trying to do, instead of how you think it might be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this easily with jQuery:

```
jQuery.trim( jQuery('label').text() )
```

That will strip the tags for you, and produce `$36.07` which you can then test with a much simpler regex.

(If you're not currently using jQuery, and don't want to use it, you can still take a look at the source code for it and see how they've implement the `.text()` function in order to emulate it.)

Hmmm, Re-reading your question, you might be asking something else - to retrieve all labels containing `$` (and ignore the inputs) you can do:

```
jQuery('label:contains($)')
```

or

```
jQuery('label').each( checkForDollars );

function checkForDollars()
{
    if ( jQuery(this).text().matches(/\$\d{2,5}/) } )
    {
        // do something
    }
)
```

Comment: non-jq version: `var labels=document.getElementsByTagName('label'); for (var len=labels.length, i=0; i<len; i++) {var c = trim(labels[i].textContent || labels[i].innerText); if (c.charAt(0)=='$') { /* do something */ } }`

Comment: trim is not a built-in function for all browsers?

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll definitely try this.

Comment: @Peter... whoops, was just writing php... yeah trim doesn't exist anywhere in javascript AFAIK. Guess the `trim` needs to go and `c.charAt(0)=='$'` needs to become a regex match.

Comment: This should work. `var labels=document.getElementsByTagName('label'); var i=-1,v,c; while (v=labels[++i]) { c = ((v.textContent||v.innerText).match(/\$\d+(?:.\d+)?/)||[])[0]; if (c) { /* do something with c */ } }` ... by the way your regex seems a little off... you forgot to escape the `$`, but even if it was escaped this would only match $10 or more. I don't think your answer will work without changing the regex.

Comment: Eeek, yes the `$` should be escaped! I copied the `{2,5}` bit from the question, but yeah, would need to be `{1,5}` to allow below $10, and of course simpler to use `\d+` if a maximum isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as the amounts are always formatted like `$36.<sup>07</sup>`.

```
function getAmount (s) { 
  var r = /\$([^<]+)<sup>(\d+)/.exec(s); 
  return r[1]+r[2]; 
}

getAmount("$36.<sup>07</sup>");
// returns "36.07"
```